# Multi-finger touch swipe event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `$('body').swipe();` functions below, which obviously can't function together because the second one cancels out what I want to do (two functions run on the same DOM element, etc.)...

The first function works as it should. Swipes left and right with TWO fingers. My problem is, this disables the normal one finger page scroll one would be able to do on the iPad.

**Question:** I want to run the swipe left & right functions with two fingers (works), however I want to enable `allowPageScroll: 'vertical'` on 1 finger swipe. How can I accomplish this? I can't figure out a way to run the options (i.e. allowPageScroll: 'vertical', threshold: 200, fingers: 2) within the `swipeLeft:` and `swipeRight:` functions only.

The plug-in used can be found here: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

```
$('body').swipe({
    swipeLeft: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('sb-swipe', 'inactive', { expires: 1 });

        //This only fires when the user swipes left
        openDashboard();

        // hide swipe instructions, if applicable
        $('div.instructions-overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    },
    swipeRight: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        //This only fires when the user swipes right
        closeDashboard();

        $('#employee-dash-btn').hide();
    },
        allowPageScroll: 'vertical',
        threshold: 200,
        fingers: 2
});

$('body').swipe({
    allowPageScroll: 'vertical',
    fingers: 1
});
```

Comment: http://quojs.tapquo.com/

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how I feel about using an entire new library just for one function. Haven't heard of this either. Is it on Apple's "approval" list?

Comment: Though I'm prob going to need to look at another solution.

Comment: Hammertime! http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ and fingerns.length http://www.appliness.com/multitouch-with-hammer-js/

Comment: Yeah, I looked at Hammer. Looks like this is the way I should have went.

Comment: Things just get more difficult as I want to apply multiple swipe gesture on the same DOM element - WITH different # of fingers. Complicated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I get something working, but not with the *TouchSwipe* plugin you link (after a lot of tests with it I just give up and try another thing).

I've use *Touchy* (1.98 kb) that can be found [here](https://github.com/jairajs89/Touchy.js), which provide support for multiple fingers up to 5. The other part to detect a swipe to the left or right is a little manual, by saving the X coordinates of the two fingers at the start of the touch event and at the end into variables.

We have just to compare if the two first coordinates are larger or smaller. Code below is a swipe to the right :

```
if (finger1Start < finger1End && finger2Start < finger2End)
```

I decide to consider a real swipe when the two fingers have move in the same direction, but it's up to you if you want to change.

Last thing, if you really want the `threshold`, you have just to save the start and end time of the event with `new Date().getTime();` subtract them and verify that they are `>` of 200ms. I can update the code if you want to.

Here is the <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm2ek/35/)</kbd>, I've tested it on iPhone 4s (iOS 7.0.3).

```js
var finger1Start,
    finger1End,
    finger2Start,
    finger2End,
    threshold = 200;

$('body').touchy({
  two: function (hand, finger1, finger2) {
    
    hand.on('start', function (points) {
      finger1Start = points[0].x;
      finger2Start = points[1].x;
    });
    
    hand.on('end', function (points) {
      finger1End = points[0].x;
      finger2End = points[1].x;
      testSwipe();
    });
  }
});

function testSwipe () {
  if (finger1Start < finger1End && finger2Start < finger2End) 
    // The two X coordinates of the fingers have swipe to the right
    if (finger1End - finger1Start >= threshold &&
        finger2End - finger2Start >= threshold) {
      $('#message').text("You have swipe to the right");
    }
    else {
      $('#message').text("Not enought swipe");
    }
        
  }
  else if (finger1Start > finger1End && finger2Start > finger2End) {
    // The two X coordinates of the fingers have swipe to the left
    if (finger1Start - finger1End >= threshold &&
        finger2Start - finger2End >= threshold) {
      $('#message').text("You have swipe to the left");
    }
    else {
      $('#message').text("Not enought swipe");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#message {
  color:green;
}

#text {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jairajs89/Touchy.js/master/touchy.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut placerat lacus. Etiam vel aliquam quam. Aenean et hendrerit elit, quis porttitor erat. Cras lacinia ornare sem ut laoreet. Sed consectetur felis at hendrerit posuere. Nam porttitor magna sed quam malesuada, eu adipiscing sapien dapibus. Praesent fermentum sem sit amet diam posuere, non vestibulum velit porttitor. Etiam sodales tellus nec mi venenatis dignissim. Aliquam metus lectus, feugiat ac tellus hendrerit, auctor sollicitudin metus.
    
    Morbi bibendum lectus erat, a iaculis tellus egestas nec. Cras adipiscing augue ac lectus placerat tempor. Fusce iaculis mollis lectus, nec mattis mi rhoncus id. Nullam scelerisque feugiat mollis. Mauris nec augue erat. Aliquam fermentum nibh ligula, vel tempus dui feugiat vel. Aliquam a consequat nisl, eu vulputate velit. Mauris pulvinar accumsan leo nec venenatis. Nullam at orci nec lorem facilisis tempor ac vitae purus. Fusce elit nulla, commodo sit amet nisi nec, euismod egestas sem. Nulla dui libero, accumsan et dignissim vitae, commodo vitae leo. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque vitae lectus sit amet lacus pulvinar imperdiet in id nulla. Nunc lacinia felis eu lobortis pretium.
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm...very intersting and light-weight script. I definitely need threshold (no idea where to start with that). So there's no way to apply the same type of "if statement" to the touchSwipe?

Comment: I thought threshold was a time notion, but it's the min number of pixel before being considered as a swipe no ? I've made it, considerating that the two fingers must swipe at 200 pixel or more to trigger the message, you can change it with the value of `threshold`. Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm2ek/35/). For you last question, I really think that *touchSwipe* is not the best way to do what you want.

Comment: Works...thanks man! You saved me some stress. really thought i could make touchSwipe work. I'll message them as well, so they can maybe look at adding/modifying their code to accommodate this.

Comment: Note, I have to wait 3 hours before I can award a bounty. ;)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped :) Yeah I think is better to do something clean with a light-weight script than try to get something working which overides basics features like scrolling with one finger. My first bounty ! I look forward ! :)

Comment: Hey - question...how would you disable vertical scroll with TWO fingers?

Comment: i also need this bro please help me @Aperçu while i am scroll with two finger it seems different..

Comment: @HariNarayanan You should create another question.